# What does the "YELLOW - L" label mean on a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube

I was looking on the [Let's Play](https://www.youtube.com/user/LetsPlay/featured) YouTube channel and saw a video with a **YELLOW - L** tag under it and was wondering what it meant.

[image: screenshot of youtube video]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is YouTube's rating system (even though justification for its existence is suspect given how difficult I found it to prove that!)

First the [colour](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/rating-restrictions-youtube-66815.html):

> If your business is a content partner with YouTube -- meaning that you have uploaded at least one video that YouTube has approved for monetization -- then you can rate your videos according to a color code. For example, if your video has no strong language, nudity, violence, sex or drug use in it, then it gets a "green" rating. If there's a mild amount of the aforementioned elements, it gets a "yellow" rating; and if there's a strong amount, it gets a "red" rating. If you apply a "no rating" label to your video, YouTube will automatically age-restrict it to viewers over age 18.

Then the [letter codes](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/146399):

[image: WA69147 example]

And finally some blurb from the same place:

> A YouTube content rating labels the mature content in a video in several categories. Each category has three options that indicate the level of mature content:
>
> •  The first option (which is also the default) indicates no mature content in the category
> •  The middle option indicates mild mature content
> •  The third option indicates mature content that should be restricted to viewers 18 and older
>
> You apply a YouTube content rating in the Video Manager. The rating categories are described below.
>
> When a user views a video with a YouTube content rating, the page displays the letter code for each rating category that has a value other than None. For categories where you've chosen the third option, a plus sign appears after the letter code. For example, the YouTube content rating for a video with explicit language, mild violence, mild drug use, and no nudity or sexual situations would appear as L+ V D.

There may be some differences between the categorisation of games and other videos.